# Optimizing searches in very large csv files

Tags: python, optimization, csv

I have a csv file with a single column, but 6.2 million rows, all containing strings between 6 and 20ish letters. Some strings will be found in duplicate (or more) entries, and I want to write these to a new csv file - a guess is that there should be around 1 million non-unique strings. That's it, really. Continuously searching through a dictionary of 6 million entries does take its time, however, and I'd appreciate any tips on how to do it. Any script I've written so far takes at least a week (!) to run, according to some timings I did.

First try:

```py
in_file_1 = open('UniProt Trypsinome (full).csv','r')
in_list_1 = list(csv.reader(in_file_1))
out_file_1 = open('UniProt Non-Unique Reference Trypsinome.csv','w+')
out_file_2 = open('UniProt Unique Trypsin Peptides.csv','w+')
writer_1 = csv.writer(out_file_1)
writer_2 = csv.writer(out_file_2)

# Create trypsinome dictionary construct
ref_dict = {}
for row in range(len(in_list_1)):
    ref_dict[row] = in_list_1[row]

# Find unique/non-unique peptides from trypsinome
Peptide_list = []
Uniques = []
for n in range(len(in_list_1)):
    Peptide = ref_dict.pop(n)
    if Peptide in ref_dict.values(): # Non-unique peptides
        Peptide_list.append(Peptide)
    else:
        Uniques.append(Peptide) # Unique peptides

for m in range(len(Peptide_list)):
    Write_list = (str(Peptide_list[m]).replace("'","").replace("[",'').replace("]",''),'')
    writer_1.writerow(Write_list)
```

Second try:

```py
in_file_1 = open('UniProt Trypsinome (full).csv','r')
in_list_1 = list(csv.reader(in_file_1))
out_file_1 = open('UniProt Non-Unique Reference Trypsinome.csv','w+')
writer_1 = csv.writer(out_file_1)

ref_dict = {}
for row in range(len(in_list_1)):
    Peptide = in_list_1[row]
    if Peptide in ref_dict.values():
        write = (in_list_1[row],'')
        writer_1.writerow(write)
    else:
        ref_dict[row] = in_list_1[row]
```

EDIT: here's a few lines from the csv file:

```
SELVQK
AKLAEQAER
AKLAEQAERR
LAEQAER
LAEQAERYDDMAAAMK
LAEQAERYDDMAAAMKK
MTMDKSELVQK
YDDMAAAMKAVTEQGHELSNEER
YDDMAAAMKAVTEQGHELSNEERR
```

Comment: Please post a few typical lines of your csv.

Comment: The problem is you are reading the entire file at once, which is not good for anyone. If you just need to output duplicated lines, `uniq -Di somefile.txt > duplicate_lines.txt`

Comment: Strange comma-separated values (csv) where there is nothing to separate, hehe! I wouldn't consider this a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hint : Python has support for lazy evaluation, better to use it when dealing with huge datasets. So :

- iterate over your csv.reader instead of building a huge in-memory list,
- don't build huge in-memory lists with ranges - use [`enumerate(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead if you need both the item and index, and just iterate over your sequence's items if you don't need the index.

Second hint : the main point of using a `dict` (hashtable) is to lookup on *keys*, not values... So don't build a huge dict that's used as a list.

Third hint : if you just want a way to store "already seen" values, use a [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: Thanks! Using a set and iterating over the reader instead really sped things up nicely - the script now takes about a minute to run. I'm interested to know exactly why/how this is so much faster, though. It's not just a little faster, but incredibly so!

Comment: First obvious reason: the way you used the dict (mainly: as an array) meant a O(n) lookup time (and with a very large 'n' value). Using a set you have O(1) lookup time. Second possible reason (but this is wild guess): with your dataset's size having two in-memory copies of your data (the list then the dict) may have eaten all available RAM and force your computer to use the swap, which is deadly slow.

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it!

Answer (score 3):

Do it with Numpy.  Roughly:

```
import numpy as np
column = 42
mat = np.loadtxt("thefile", dtype=[TODO])
uniq = set(np.unique(mat[:,column]))
for row in mat:
    if row[column] not in uniq:
        print row
```

You could even vectorize the output stage using `numpy.savetxt` and the char-array operators, but it probably won't make very much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good in Python, so I don't know how the 'in' works, but your algorithm seems to run in n².
Try to sort your list after reading it, with an algo in n log(n), like quicksort, it should work better.
Once the list is ordered, you just have to check if two consecutive elements of the list are the same.

So you get the reading in n, the sorting in n log(n) (at best), and the comparison in n.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that the numpy solution is the best, I'm curious whether we can speed up the given example. My suggestions are:

- skip csv.reader costs and just read the line
- rb to skip the extra scan needed to fix newlines
- use bigger file buffer sizes (read 1Meg, write 64K is probably good)
- use the dict keys as an index - key lookup is much faster than value lookup

I'm not a numpy guy, so I'd do something like

```
in_file_1 = open('UniProt Trypsinome (full).csv','rb', 1048576)
out_file_1 = open('UniProt Non-Unique Reference Trypsinome.csv','w+', 65536)

ref_dict = {}
for line in in_file_1:
    peptide = line.rstrip()
    if peptide in ref_dict:
        out_file_1.write(peptide + '\n')
    else:
        ref_dict[peptide] = None
```